# Invalid nifi.web.https configuration in nifi.properties when trying log in nifi

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I'm new to nifi, I downloaded nifi, I'm trying to log in, but I can't enter the address:https://127.0.0.1:8443/

Logs:

```
 2023-07-10 16:16:34,682 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Failed to start web server... shutting down.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid nifi.web.https configuration in nifi.properties
at org.apache.nifi.web.server.connector.FrameworkServerConnectorFactory.<init>(FrameworkServerConnectorFactory.java:89)
at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.configureConnectors(JettyServer.java:738)
at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.init(JettyServer.java:207)
at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.initialize(JettyServer.java:1074)
at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:164)
at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:83)
at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:332)
Caused by: org.apache.nifi.security.util.TlsException: The truststore properties are not valid
at org.apache.nifi.security.util.SslContextFactory.getTrustManagers(SslContextFactory.java:181)
at org.apache.nifi.security.util.SslContextFactory.createSslContext(SslContextFactory.java:67)
at org.apache.nifi.web.server.connector.FrameworkServerConnectorFactory.<init>(FrameworkServerConnectorFactory.java:86)
6 common frames omitted
2023-07-10 16:16:34,685 INFO [Thread-0] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Application Server shutdown started
2023-07-10 16:16:34,686 INFO [Thread-0] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Application Server shutdown completed
 `
```

Maybe someone knows why it's not working?

Comment: What java and nifi versions you are using? Did you change any nifi configurations after download?

Comment: I am using java 11 and nifi 1.21.0

Comment: I didn't change anything in nifi.properties, I made changes in bootstrap.conf because I had a problem with memory - I changed JVM memory settings to:
java.arg.2=-Xms4096m
java.arg.3=-Xmx8192m

Comment: @MWM Please show variables in `nifi.properties` in section `# web properties #`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: error: `Caused by: org.apache.nifi.security.util.TlsException: The truststore properties are not valid` sounds like you changed `nifi.security...` or truststore  parameters...